# ZAProxy Jenkins plug in how to configure browser for ajax spider

Tags: jenkins, zap

I recently started using the Zap proxy plug-in for Jenkins. I am using ZAP version 2.5.0. I have managed to configure this plug-in in Jenkins. Is there any way I can choose a different browser for the AJAX Spider URL(instead of default Firefox)?
    In the standalone version of Zap, there is an option to choose different browsers.

If I use Firefox(version 49) I am getting the following error. So while running from Jenkins I am planing to use phantomjs or htmlunit.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------  

Status spider = running
    Alerts number =         ApiResponseElement numberOfAlerts = 92

    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    xpi DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1478780397489   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1478780397490   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1478780397494   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1478780397495   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.3
    1478780397495   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1478780397495   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
    1478780397496   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1478780397497   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
    1478780397499   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1478780397499   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1478780397499   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1478780397499   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1478780397499   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1478780397500   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1478780397520   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1478780397520   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1478780397521   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1478780397521   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1478780397522   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1478780397522   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1478780400822   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1478780400822   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1478780400823   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1478780403674   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1478780403674   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1478780403674   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1478780403695   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1478780403706   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1478780403726   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1478780404682   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1478780404682   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1478780404683   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1478780404687   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1478780404737   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1478780404994   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1478780405052   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1478780419483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.3
    1478780419483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
    1478780419483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
    1478780420249   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
    1478780420250   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1478780420250   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
    1478780420250   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
    1478780420251   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1478780420251   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1478780420253   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1478780420254   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1478780420255   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1478780420258   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
    1478780420261   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriverImpl(ExtensionSelenium.java:241)
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.selenium.ExtensionSelenium.getWebDriver(ExtensionSelenium.java:224)
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spiderAjax.SpiderThread$AjaxSpiderBrowserBuilder.get(SpiderThread.java:358)
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spiderAjax.SpiderThread$AjaxSpiderBrowserBuilder.get(SpiderThread.java:329)
        at com.google.inject.util.Providers$3.get(Providers.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.crawljax.core.CrawlController.call(CrawlController.java:65)
        at com.crawljax.core.CrawljaxRunner.call(CrawljaxRunner.java:37)
        at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spiderAjax.SpiderThread.run(SpiderThread.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    55912 [Thread-8] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spiderAjax.SpiderThread  - Failed to start browser firefox
    com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing **zaproxy-plugin** will stop being distributed but they will allow the existing users of the plugin to use the current version. The plugin was long abandoned and as far as i know didn't produce 1 to 1 results with the UI (from my own testing). Furthermore it was never an official zap plugin but rather made by some users.

An Official OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Jenkins Plugin is coming soon, i'm the lead developer on the project. Check the Jenkins marketplace next week or the ZAP blogs for more information next week.

To answer your questions in regards to the official plugin.

**Is there any way I can choose a different browser for the AJAX Spider URL(instead of default Firefox)?** Not at the moment, it currently only supports Firefox.

**I use Firefox(version 49)**
You should not use the latest and greatest version of firefox, most third party open source software generally takes time to catch up. Having said that, I use Firefox 46 and have no issues. See [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsSeleniumIntro) for more details on supported browsers.

P.S. Note for the future, useful to post which version of the plugin you're using.

*EDIT*: firefox is the default, it's possible to change the browser through the command line though.

`-config ajaxSpider.browserId=htmlunit`
`-config ajaxSpider.browserId=phantomjs`

If that will work and won't cause issues with either the old zaproxy-plugin or the new one, i don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the update ,
As suggested I have copied Zap Latest version to Jenkins and downgraded Firefox 46 .The issue now I am having is while closing  down Firefox – it is crashing the .Here is the crash report.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't maange upload full log here, updated crash report in Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/f_NTdO4-eno